# How to customize the 'write' to instrument?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, device, python, instrumentation

I'm communicating with Power Supply [RIGOL DP832A](http://www.rigolna.com/products/dc-power-supplies/dp800/dp832a/) via Ethernet.

```
from vxi11 import Instrument
dev = Instrument('192.168.1.186', 'inst0')

answer = dev.ask('*IDN?').strip()
print(answer)

channel = 3
channel = str(channel)

volts= 22
volts = str(volts)

current = 2.3
current = str(current)

selchannel = 'CH'+ channel
mypass = 'APPL ' + selchannel + ','

mypass = mypass + volts + ','

mypass = mypass + current

print (mypass)
dev.write(mypass)
```

In my `expdp832a.py` all the stuff with channel, volts and current I'm doing because later I'll be taking channel input, volts input and current input from the user and setting it to the values passed by him say via a function like `set_powersupply(channel, volts, current)`.

When I'm printing the value of `mypass`, it's `string` with the value `APPL CH3, 22, 2.3` but  still my PowerSupply displays `invalid command`.

Instead if I directly pass it as `dev.write('APPL CH3, 22, 2.3')` Everything works properly and Power Supply Channel 3 is set with volots and current values.

What is wrong in the earlier method? If I want it to be user-selectable, I need to pass channel, volts and current values as input from user and not as hard-coded values.

Comment: Are yo usure the strings are exactly the same down to whitespace and null termination? You say the string is `'APPL CH3, 22, 2.3'`, but in your code I don't see you adding the spaces after the commas, for example.

Comment: To the close voters: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/2028

Comment: @JYelton, I didn't vote to close, but my guess is people who think this is off-topic think it's a programming question (and specifically a Python language question) rather than a test equipment question.

Comment: @ThePhoton I can see how that could be the case. Personally, I find the question interesting/relevant because I also have Rigol test equipment and wouldn't mind knowing how this is done.

Comment: try this: dev = Instrument('192.168.1.186', term_char = ',')

Comment: @ThePhoton - I think there was a recent question about Rigol Power supply and Python. I thought that was about setting up Python and getting started, and was 'starting programming'. This seems to be 'spot on topic' to me. +1 This might be my favourite question of the week. ...  3 hours since Vladimir Cravero made the `term_char = ','` suggestion. Did it work? I'm on tenterhooks to learn the answer :-)

Comment: @gbulmer, again, I haven't voted to close. I'm waiting to see what the answer is. But if `term_char` is used in the library the same way it is in the related C APIs, I don't think Vlad's answer is going to work. term_char should probably be '\r' or '\n'. And really it should only be needed for a very poorly compliant instrument. Also, OP's test using a string literal instead of a variable should have failed, if this was going to be the solution.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I apologise, I wasn't clear. I was not suggesting you had down-voted. I was intending to re-inforce your point about people mis-interpreting this as "a programming question", maybe because there was a similar looking question earlier this week. Deep sadness about Vlad's comment not making it work :-(

Comment: @gbulmer, To be more clear, if the answer is "this instrument needs a \n termination character on each message", then that's on topic. If the answer is something like "when you concatenate strings in Python it allocates the character array differently and the vxi11 library is not properly changing this to a null-terminated string before passing it to the underlying C library" then it's getting real close to off topic. That's why I'm waiting to find out the answer before deciding whether to flag or not. (And I wouldn't downvote it, just flag it, since it's otherwise well-written)

Comment: @gbulmer, also, sorry if I am sounding argumentative. Just trying to fit my thoughts into the limited space of a comment. And some of those thoughts are more meant for OP than for you.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I like a good argument, so "sounding argumentative" is okay !-) By 'good' I mean sane, grounded in reality, and based on evidence. I believe I understand your commentary and analysis. I am new here, but AFAICT, the overwhelming majority of people who have progressed past one or two questions behave very decently and helpfully to each other and new posters.

Comment: `'APPL CH3, 22, 2.3'` or `'APPL CH3,22,2.3'` both work.. so I guess space after a comma is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get better control of the string formatting in Python (version 2.6 or later), use the built-in `str.format` function. For example:

```
channel = 3
volts= 22
current = 2.3
#
# example with spaces
mypass="APPL CH{0}, {1}, {2}".format(channel, volts, current)
# mypass contains 'APPL CH3, 22, 2.3'
#
# example without spaces
mypass="APPL CH{0},{1},{2}".format(channel, volts, current)
# mypass contains 'APPL CH3,22,2.3'
```

Inside the format string, the `{0}` is replaced with the first value (channel), the `{1}` is replaced with the second value (volts), etc.

Like most strings in python, backslash substitution is used, so `\r` is character 0x13 (CR) and `\n` is character 0x10 (LF). When used for instrument control, the remote instrument may require one or both of these line end characters. I don't know whether dev.write() handles line end for you or not.

Good programming practice is to enclose this in a function or a class, if there isn't already a ready-made class for this device.

```
def RigolDp832aMypass(channel, volts, current):
    """Return a string formatted with voltage and current command for RIGOL DP832A power supply"""
    return "APPL CH{0}, {1}, {2}".format(channel, volts, current)

# Test
print(RigolDp832aMypass(channel=3, volts=22, current=2.3))
# Expect 'APPL CH3, 22, 2.3'
#
# You could then invoke dev.write(RigolDp832aMypass(channel=3, volts=22, current=2.3))
```

Tested with Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3 on win32.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a ton! and yeah, dev.write() handles endline.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code:

```
channel = 3
channel = str(channel)

volts= 22
volts = str(volts)

current = 2.3
current = str(current)

selchannel = 'CH'+ channel
mypass = 'APPL ' + selchannel + ','

mypass = mypass + volts + ','

mypass = mypass + current

print (mypass)
```

Through:

> Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin

It printed

```
APPL CH3,22,2.3
```

Which is what I would have expected (and The Photon raised as an issue in a comment), and is *not exactly* the same as your Python, which prints `APPL CH3, 22, 2.3`

Which version of Python are you using? It looks like it might be Python 3.

Would you please do the experiment of running `dev.write('APPL CH3,22,2.3')` and report back?

My suspicion is Python is interpreting character strings somewhere. However I can't imagine why that should matter to the power supply.

Comment: I tried it with `dev.write('APPL CH3,22,2.3')` and it works fine so I guess space after comma is not a probblem.

Comment: @pyL - Okay. So try one of the (many) ways to format a string, for example MarkU's suggestion of `mypass="APPL CH{0},{1},{2}".format(channel, volts, current)` instead of building the string in pieces.

Comment: Sure, I'll be trying it soon. Thanks a lot to everyone for help. I'll let you know when I get it to work. :) Thanks again